# SQL Server memory usage monitoring

Tags: sql-server, memory, monitoring

I want to know exact memory usage by SQL Server, which parameter or query use for this? Please suggest with an example.

For example I had configured max server memory at 8 GB, in task manager SQL Server memory usage is shown as 8 GB. So I am not able to know what exact memory usage is now by SQL Server current connection is showing zero in perfmon.

Answer (score 0):

Task manager shows 8GB memory usage because that's how much it is actually using. SQL Server, by design, never releases the memory that it grabs. It caches all the data that it has ever fetched from the disk and keeps it in memory so that the next query is much faster. Even if there are no connections, SQL Server will hold on to all its data so that the next connection will not have to go back to the disk to get data.